# How to iterate through a 2D LinkedHashSet and print its contents?

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I am using a 2D LinkedHashSet for my program. I was wondering how I can iterate through the two dimensional HashSet and print its contents without doing this:

System.out.println(name of initialized HashSet)

Here is my code for initialization of the 2D LinkedHashSet:

```
LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> block = new LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>();
```

Comment: "*`System.out.println(name of initialized HashSet)`*" - What is wrong with this line?

Comment: I do not want to simply print the 2D LinkedHashSet. I would like to iterate through every element in the 2D LinkedHashSet and print each individual value. Similar to how you can iterate through a 2D Array with an n^2 loop. I want to learn how to iterate through the 2D LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2 loops for this, similar to how you would for an array:

```
for (Set<String> innerSet : block) {
    for (String string : innerSet) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

You can also use streams to print each element:

```
block.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I have a quick question regarding this. Is it possible to edit values in the LinkedHashSet after they have been added?

Comment: @LavaMaster You would have to remove the value and add a new value. You cannot, however, do this in a for loop, or you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can use streams to modify the values. But that is a little more advanced.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Essentially what I am trying to do is to check if the 2D LinkedHashSet contains a specific String. If the String is already contained in the 2D LinkedHashSet, then I want to find its location in the 2D LinkedHashSet and add another value there.

Answer (score 2):

If one wants to use a functional solution, one could use the following:

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/5HvkST)

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Streamify {
    public static void main (final String... args) {
        final LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> block = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        final LinkedHashSet<String> lineOne = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        lineOne.add("Hello");
        lineOne.add("World");
        block.add(lineOne);
        final LinkedHashSet<String> lineTwo = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        lineTwo.add("Hi");
        lineTwo.add("Universe");
        block.add(lineTwo);

        block.forEach(line -> {
            line.forEach(System.out::print);
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a functional way to accomplish this, it is not technically a stream-based solution. The `.forEach` is a default method on the `Iterable` interface, and is different than the `.forEach` on `Stream`

Comment: True that. Corrected.